# android zxing within a frame

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am quite new to Android development, but i have managed it to build a small barcode scanner using the zxing library integrated to my app (not as intent to be seperately installed).
What i am looking for now is a solution to put "the scanning" inside a frame or something within my main activity, so that not everytime the user want to scan something a new app (or at leat a new activity) is opened.
Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUT9Y.png